# A Fourier operator $F_{1}^{-1}(1+\xi_{1}^{2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}F_{1}$ is linear under derivatives?

Tags: linear-transformations, fourier-transform

We define an operator 
$$
Rv(x)=F^{-1}(1+\xi^{2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}Fv,
$$
where $(Fv)(\xi)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}v(x)e^{-ix\xi}\ dx$.

> Is this operator linear under derivatives? I mean,  $$
>  \frac{\partial}{\partial x}Rv=R(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}). $$

Note that $F\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v=i\xi Fv$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F^{-1}v(\xi)=F^{-1}i\xi v(\xi)$.
So, 
$$
R(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x})=F^{-1}\frac{i\xi}{(1+\xi^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}Fv=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F^{-1}\frac{i\xi}{(1+\xi^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}}Fv=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}Rv(x).
$$

Am I right?

Comment: I would say "does this operator *commute* with derivatives", rather than "is this operator linear under derivatives". You reasoning is correct

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Okay. Thanks for the comment.